# Why did the israeli-palestinian conflict start?

Tags: israel, palestine

I want to get a sense of why the conflict started. What was the major reason.

Comment: Asking what caused the conflict wouldn't be too broad, but to answer the more open-ended "who are the players?" and "why decisions were made."  One would have to provide a list of players/decision reasons of an undefined length.

Comment: I've been trying to think of a way to answer this but my answer would either have to be one sentence long or an entire book long. It will definitely have to be narrowed down. Do you maybe want to know the causes of a single flareup in the conflict (e.g. an intifada or operation in Gaza or war)?

Comment: Same reason as all conflicts. Two groups of people competing for the same resource.

Comment: Because Isreal was established and the Muslims wanted them dead...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wikipedia has [several](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israeli%E2%80%93Palestinian_conflict) [pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Israeli%E2%80%93Palestinian_conflict) on this subject ([full index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Israeli%E2%80%93Palestinian_conflict)).  Books have been written on it.  It's way too involved to explain everything here.

The short form is:

- The land in the British Mandate was to be divided into a Jewish state and a Arab one.  Israel declared itself independent (in those borders) in 1948, and the neighboring Arab countries attacked it (as the climax of years of conflict while under British control).  By the end of that war, Israel was larger than originally planned.
- In 1967, Israel and the neighboring Arab countries went to war again.  Israel captured more land by the end of that war, which included the West Bank and the Gaza Strip.
- Since there were already Palestinians living in the captured areas (and others who had left and wanted to return), and since there was never an official cease fire, the status of those lands remains up in the air 50 years later.  Israel can't officially incorporate them (per international law) because they're considered "occupied territory", but they can't simply pull back out for various reasons (including security, access to certain areas and resources, and the presence of Israeli settlers in that area).
- Israel has granted some level of self-governance to these areas, but the Gaza Strip's elected government is run by Hamas, who consider themselves freedom fighters against Israel and are sworn to its destruction.

Comment: I've tried to make this as neutral as I could.  Please let me know if you see a better way to write it.

Comment: -1 - while a decent answer, it makes it seem as if the conflict started in 1948 (ignoring Mufti of Jerusalem, never mind even earlier history)

Comment: @DVK - That's a valid point, and there was certainly tension and conflict between Zionists and Arabs, but it wasn't a conflict with *Israel* before then.  I've added a parenthetical statement to acknowledge the earlier conflicts.

Comment: I think you need an earlier paragraph touching on Zionist/Jewish immigration to Israel/Palestine, with tension and violence from that time. It's necessary to understand why the territory was divided in the first place - and how two hostile populations got so intertwined to begin with.

Comment: Additionally, my understanding is that Israel _can_ annex the occupied territory, but chooses not to, primarily because that would require absorbing all the Palestinians as full Israeli citizens - creating huge financial and security cost for Israel, and a massive anti-=Israel shift in the voting body.

Comment: Who started the 1967 conflict is open to debate.

Comment: @SVilcans - Agreed, but almost everything here is open for debate (and *is* debated extensively).  In that case, Israel attacked first, but the surrounding countries were clearly mobilizing.  But that's why I open by saying "It's complicated, go read a book".

Comment: @SVilcans No it is not. Egypt started the conflict by blockading the Strait of Tiran, and a blockade is an act of war.

Answer (score 1):

In post WWII times the British Empire, who controlled the Israel/Palestine territory, was collapsing, the Zionist movement was gaining more acceptance due to the holocaust, the United Nations was recently formed and decolonization was a major focus. All these factors combined to create the United Nations Special Committee on Palestine, which came up with the plan to divide the land into a Jewish state and an Arab State with Jerusalem to be in an international trusteeship.

The UN adopted this resolution and Israel and Palestine were created, however the Arab League rejected this plan and declared war on Israel. Since then Israel has been in open war or varying states of ceasefires with its Arab neighbors. Essentially the conflict is a result of the surrounding Arab nations not agreeing with the decisions of the allied powers via the UN. If you go even further back in history the are about five other countries/empires with claims to the land in every century.

Comment: -1 - while a decent answer, it makes it seem as if the conflict started in 1948 (ignoring Mufti of Jerusalem, never mind even earlier history)